# Change yardoc serialized_path

Tags: ruby, yard

Right now Yardoc will generate docs like: doc/ModuleName.html, doc/ModuleName/ClassName.html and doc/ModuleName/ClassName/method_name.html I was wondering how I can adjust `serialized_path` (without monkey patching everything) to do something like: doc/ModuleName/index.html doc/ModuleName/ClassName/index.html and doc/ModuleName/ClassName/method_name/index.html

Comment: Why you want to do that? If it's for prettier URLs you can achieve that with rewriting.

Comment: @slartibartfast Lets say I do take this suggestion, I would then be stuck with sloppy URLs and having to manually edit a bunch of links or to 301 redirect (which again it just plain sloppy), that is not ideal, at all...

Comment: By rewriting I meant something on server configuration level. You can add a rewrite rule that says something like "if there is no file with this name, try appending .html". Even on shared (apache) hostings you can probably add this kind of rule in your local `.htaccess`

Comment: @slartibartfast And I didn't mean that? I think you are a bit confused so let me clarify for you. Links are outputted as ModuleName/ClassName.html, or ../_index.html (until I fixed that -- just it using _) I do not want that, I will not use a Dirty front-end hack to create pretty URL's (which would still leave the outputted links relative and to .html files and would again require another dirty front-end hack to 301) that creates as mess for management, that creates a mess period.  I'm no fan of dirty hacks because they always need to be fixed later, development procrastination is bad :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to monkey patch (from what I've noticed, after 2 days of searching I found no other way) So...Create a file named yardoc_pretty-uris.rb and when you run yardoc do `-e yardo_pretty-print.rb`.

yardoc_pretty-uris.rb contents:

```
module YARD
  module Serializers
    class FileSystemSerializer
      def serialized_path(object)
        return object if object.is_a?(String)

        if object.is_a?(CodeObjects::ExtraFileObject)
          fspath = ["file.#{object.name}.#{@extension}"]
        else
          objname = "top-level-namespace"
          objname = object.name.to_s if object != YARD::Registry.root

          # Make this shit pretty URL's prease.....
          fspath = [objname, "index.#{@extension}"]

          if object.namespace && object.namespace.path != ""
            fspath.unshift(*object.namespace.path.split(CodeObjects::NSEP))
          end
        end

        fspath.map! do |part|
          part.downcase!
          part.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-_\.]/, '')
        end

        File.join(fspath)
      end
    end
  end
end
```